# I do have many batch files but i need to call them in VBScript one after the other

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I do have many batch files and I have a VBScript. But I need to call all the batch files in VBScript one after the other?

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: SO is not a place where we do your work for you. We'll (try to) help you with problems in your code, but we do require that you made an effort yourself first. And show us what you already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Especially if you can google the solutions to those problems quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point you in the right direction:
Perhaps an [array of vars](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_arrays.htm) (strings), each with a fully-qualified filepath to the batch files.

```
dim batchFiles
batchFiles = Array("C:\scripts\bat1.bat","C:\scripts\bat2.bat")
```

Then you can write a `for each` loop to loop over each of those and execute them, could could make it a multi-dimensional array, array of arrays or use a parallel array to define arguments/parameters for each execution.  Of course you could import the list of batch file locations from a file or some other script if you wanted to clean that up a bit.